# Lodash get last item in array in path

Tags: javascript, arrays, get, lodash

I'm using Lodash to get the following data:

```
  dateSeen: _.get(record, 'availableDates.0.dateSeen.0'),
```

However, instead of getting the first item in the availableDate array, and then the first item in dataSeen, I would like to get the last item for both.

I've seen that Lodash has a _last() function, but I'm trying to figure out how I can use it here.

Thanks